# Compare string and floats in python

Tags: python

I have a two lists with values that I want to compare. If the value can be converted to a float, I want to compare the floats else I just want to compare the values as strings. How can I make that distinction to check whether a value can be converted to float or not?

Comment: What have tried?  What code do you have so far?  This is not "do my homework.com".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way should be to just try to convert them to floats, and if that fails, fall back to a compare on strings:

```
def floatstrcmp(left, right):
   try:
      return cmp(float(left), float(right))
   except ValueError:
      return cmp(left, right)
```

Comment: Always be careful when comparing floats !! Floats are inaccurate by nature and exact float comparison will fail if the said floats are calculations results.

Comment: Note, that `float(obj)` can raise TypeError (e.g. None) and AttributeError (python class instance) in addition to ValueError.